# XmlPullParser resource management

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

How does XmlPullParser manage resources?
Why are there no `close()`, `release()` or some similar method?

For example I want to read XML from a file:

```
    final XmlPullParserFactory xppf = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    final XmlPullParser xpp = xppf.newPullParser();
    xpp.setInput(new FileInputStream("test/file.xml));
    while (xpp.next() // parsing...
    // ...
```

Who should close this `FileInputStream` and release resources?

If `XmlPullParser` will close `FileInputStream` automagically after whole file has been read, what will happen if an exception is thrown or if I never call `xpp.nextXXX()`?

Will it close stream anyway, so I shouldn't worry about resource management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You opened the file with

```
new FileInputStream("test/file.xml)
```

so you should close it.  Also, you should be aware that XmlPullParser will throw exceptions.